# How to upload files to mongodb GridFs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working with mongodb version 4.2.8 and I am trying to save to the mongofiles a pdf created on the server,  without implementing any other third party package (mongoose, multer, etc.).
The problem with my code is that I don't know how to require the `Grid` functions.
Following is just a sample of the code I am working on.

```
  const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  const Grid = require('mongodb').GridFSBucket; // cant figure out how it works.
  // const Grid = require('mongodb').Grid; // not a function
  mongo.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }, async (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  var db = client.db('brickfy')
  var grid = new Grid(client, 'fs');
  var writestream = grid.createWriteStream({
    metadata:{category:'example' user:'user'},
    content_type:'application/pdf',
    filename: '/path/my-pdf'
  });
  writestream.on('close', function (file) {
    console.log(file);
  }

});
```

I tried to learn with this example: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/grid.html but instead of using new Buffer upload an image. the other examples I found in internet were using mongoose and grid-fs-stream. This is one example using all the tools I dont want to install https://data-flair.training/blogs/mongodb-gridfs-tutorial/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I upload files with mongodb gridfs (without using external libraries)?

Comment: You need to use the driver to use gridfs.

Comment: is the gridfs driver this one https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream or is there any other from mongo?

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/

Comment: I already added mongodb to my project.

Comment: The code below it's what I used to make it work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make it work the code below:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const mongoClient = new mongo.MongoClient(URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongo.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }, async (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  function uploadFileToMongo (){
   DEF.mongo.gridfsUploadStream = async function(file, bucketName, metadata, filetype, id = undefined, malwareChecks = true) {
    // this function bypasses the need to save the file
    // before uploading to the database
    let bucket = new mongo.GridFSBucket('databaseName', { bucketName: bucketName });
    const stream_opts = { metadata: metadata, contentType: filetype };
    
    let uploadStream = undefined;
    uploadStream = bucket.openUploadStreamWithId(id, file.filename, stream_opts);

    try {
      await function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          file.pipe(uploadStream)
            .on('finish', resolve)
            .on('error', reject);
        });
      }();
      return { ok: true };
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e, 'upload-500');
    }
  };
  }
});
```